# Compare two sql tables to work out whats missing.

Tags: sql, sybase, matching, analysis

I have a two tables which *SHOULD* contain the same information.

table 1 - invoice headers (customer name etc)
table 2 - invoice lines (stock reference etc)

table 1 is basically a summary of each matching line of table 2. I know table 1 is correct and contains all the data.

They keys that match would be the date,invoice ref and account number.

Is there a way to see whats missing from table two?

Comment: Can you share your tables' structure please?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Left Outer Join to show what exists in the left table but not the right. In this case, the left table is your headers and right is invoice lines. There are a lot of examples on MSDN pages and google queries turn up plenty of results. (Trying not to provide an example here because this is an awesome opportunity to learn from experience.)

Comment: Thank you I will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use:

```
Select * from table 1 
minus
Select * from table 2;
```

Or you can use

```
SELECT column1 [, column2 ]
FROM table1 [, table2 ]
[WHERE condition]

EXCEPT

SELECT column1 [, column2 ]
FROM table1 [, table2 ]
[WHERE condition]
```

The SQL EXCEPT clause/operator is used to combine two SELECT statements and returns rows from the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement.